# useDynLib() error and compileAttributes returns nothing: embedding a C library into an R package

Tags: c, r, makefile, rcpp, r-package

I have a C package which builds a executable with several argument flags. One compiles the code with a Makefile (I know, this needs to change for the R package) and an executable is created to be run via

`$ ./codeName -f path/inputfile -o path/outputfile -p ## -s "type"`

My goal is to integrate several of the functions used in this C package to be used with an R library. I take a look at some examples on `github.com/cran` of R packages using C. In Writing R Extensions, it explains how I could use `.Call()` and `Makevars` to call the C functions from R. I would like to avoid that like the plague. However, it looks like this would require significant re-writing with `SEXP` object--so I turn to Rcpp (yeah!)

I create the package `Rcpp.package.skeleton("packageName")`

Great. Within R, I do the following:

```
$ R
> library(devtools)
> build()  # works!
> install() # works!
> library(packageName)
> rcpp_hello_world()
## expected output
```

Everything works. Then I add my C package into `/src`. I then execute `Rcpp::compileAttributes()` in the package root directory via R--nothing happens and nothing is output, which is expected, as I haven't changed the C code at all yet.

I try installing with the commands above: `devtools::build()` and `devtools::install()`. Via the `Makefile`, it looks like the C code compiles perfectly! But then there's this issue:

```
** R
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Error in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib) : 
  shared object ‘packageName.so’ not found
Error: loading failed
Execution halted'
ERROR: loading failed
```

Well, that's somewhat confusing, and I don't know why that has occurred, but the snag is the `useDynLib("packageName")` in the NAMESPACE. If I remove this, the C code appears to compile and the package installs via the `build/install` commands above. `rcpp_hello_world()` still works.

(1) Why does this error `‘packageName.so’ not found` appear now, and can I get around it?

(This question has nothing to do with Rcpp.)

Then, I go to a `.c` file. I add

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
```

to a `*.c` file and `//[[Rcpp::export]]` before a function I would like to import. (I'm not sure that's going to work in `*.c`, or in a C header file.)

Next, I go to the package root directory, open R and try this:

```
$ R
> library(Rcpp)
> compileAttributes()
```

That runs without error. However, no `RcppExports.R` and `RcppExports.cpp` were generated. Compiling the C code also results in the error that it cannot find `#include <Rcpp.h>`.

(2) Why would `compileAttributes()` not function in this environment? I must be incorrectly using `Rcpp` and `//[[Rcpp::export]]` in order to wrap these C functions into R-usable format.

Comment: You could start from the other side with a working package as created by `Rcpp.package.skeleton()` or the equivalent function in RStudio and then compare. "Something" must be different here.

Comment: Also, a very obvious one:  Rcpp and `compileAttributes()` expect C++ code.  Not C code.  So files ending in `.c` are ignored _by design_.  Just rename your files ...

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Thanks for the input. Changing the extension to `.cpp` results in some compilation errors...In order to keep the C code unchanged, I may have to resort to writing `SEXP`...

Comment: _Either_ you want C++ and Rcpp and can get converters written for you (ie no, you don't have to use `SEXP`) _or_ you want plain C in which case your quest for `compileAttributes()` is wrong.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel In this case then, unless I could pass through the C code through `cFunction()`, there's no way integrating vanilla C code would be made easier with Rcpp (unless I could translate the C code into C++)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What would you call this function?  C code?

```
int fib(int n) { 
   if (n < 2) return n;
   return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);
}
```

It passes as both C and C++ code. So let's call it C code.

You can clearly interface this from R via Rcpp with the following caller:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
int callFib(int n) {
   return fib(n);
}
```

Stick them all together *into a C++ file so that Rcpp can operate on them*  (see comments) and you are all set.

```
R> library(Rcpp)
R> sourceCpp("/tmp/ex.cpp")

R> callFib(10)
[1] 55
R>
```

The complete file is below.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

int fib(int n) { 
  if (n < 2) return n;
  return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);
}


// [[Rcpp::export]]
int callFib(int n) {
  return fib(n);
}

/*** R
callFib(10)
*/
```

Comment: I understand your comments above now. Thanks

Comment: So the same code wrappers created by `compileAttributes()` with C++ code cannot exist when I renamed the files as *.C code? I have no idea what I'm doing