# How do I create an R package that depends on a shared library with Rcpp?

Tags: c, r, dll, rcpp

I have a shared library `libbcd.so` generated from `C` source code.
I also have some interface code `Rinterface.h, Rinterface.cpp`, which looks as follows:

**Rinterface.h**:

```
#pragma once

#include <R.h>
#include <Rcpp.h>
extern "C" {
#include "bcd.h"
}

void call_bcd();
```

**Rinterface.cpp**

```
#include "Rinterface.h"

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void call_bcd() {
    mm_problem* pr = mm_problem_alloc();
    bcd_vars* vars = bcd_vars_alloc();
    bcd(pr, vars);
}
```

Where `mm_problem_alloc(), bcd_vars_alloc(), bcd(mm_problem*, bcd_vars*)` are all functions from `libbcd.so` and `mm_problem` and `bcd_vars` are user defined types from `libbcd.so`.

I have created a package with `Rcpp.package.skeleton("bcd")` put the **Rinterface** files under `src` folder with the following **Makevars**

```
PKG_CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include/ -I/path/to/bcd/headers/
PKG_LIBS=-L/path/to/bcd/library/file -lbcd
```

- I can create the interface library with `R CMD SHLIB Rinterface.cpp`
- I can also build a package tarball with `R CMD build .`

If I try to install the package from source with `install.packages("/path/to/bcd_1.0.tar.gz", type = "source")` after the compilation step I get an error when it tries to load `libbcd.so`:

```
** R
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘bcd’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/home/gomfy/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/00LOCK-bcd/00new/bcd/libs/bcd.so':
  libbcd.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47517121/usedynlib-error-and-compileattributes-returns-nothing-embedding-a-c-library-i) it seems to me that a workaround would be to rename the `.c` source files of `libbcd.so` to `.cpp` and then put them in the `src` folder. Is this correct?

In general, what is a recommended way of leveraging Rcpp to be able to call a third party shared library from `R`? I've found a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41210595/s4-object-with-a-pointer-to-a-c-struct) but it doesn't go into details of building the package. I've looked at **Writing R extensions** `vignette("Rcpp-introduction")`, `vignette("Rcpp-package")` but I wasn't able to come to a clear conclusion. So, I'd appreciate an expert's help here. Thank you!

Comment: See also here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58482765/8416610

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In short, you can't.

A *system-level* shared library will be loaded on demand for you by `ld.so` (on Linux, similar on other OSs and same idea).  So if your package depends on a non-standard or uncommon shared library, tough luck.  *This can only work if `ld.so` knows about it, and an R package cannot make it so.*

What you *can* do is bundle the sources of your `libbcd` *with your package* and them built as a *static library* linked to from your package.  That will work.  As will the simpler approach of maybe just putting the source files of `libbcd` into the package `src/` directory -- and R will take care of the rest.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response!